# JSX this.state.STATE.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Issue: this.state.previousWords.map() is nor recognized as a function

I have a hangman app that is trying to render previously seen words onto the page in their own line. The issue happens when a new word is added to the array in the state previousWords: []. When the page tries to re-render this it errors stating "TypeError: this.state.previousWords.map is not a function." Below is the code snippet where the error is happening.

Based off a prior project this is correct syntax (code has been included). I need help understanding why this is not recognized and how to fix it.

```
<div className="col-3">
                        <h3>Previous words:</h3>
                        <br></br>

                        {this.state.previousWords.length ? (
                            
                            <div>
                                {this.state.previousWords.map( (value, index) => (

                                    <div 
                                    key={index}
                                    className="row">

                                        {value}

                                    </div>

                                ))}
                            </div>

                        ):(<></>)}
                    </div>
```

Prior app with functioning .map statement:

```
{this.state.events.length ? (
                                        
                                        <Dropdown.Menu>
                                            {this.state.events.map(events => (
                                                <Dropdown.Item
                                                key={events.event_id}
                                                /* TODO: onClick() */
                                                >
                                                    {events.title}
                                                </Dropdown.Item>
                                                ))}
                                        </Dropdown.Menu>

                                    ) : (

                                        <Dropdown.Menu>
                                            <Dropdown.Item>No Events Available</Dropdown.Item>
                                        </Dropdown.Menu>

                                    )}
```

exact error

```
 325 | 
  326 | <div className="col-3">
  327 |     <h3>Previous words:</h3>
> 328 |     <br></br>
      | ^  329 |     <>{console.log(this.state.previousWords)}</>
  330 | 
  331 |     { this.state.previousWords.length ? (
```

Setting the state for previousWord:

```
 if( this.loss() ) {

                                let previousWords = [...this.state.previousWords];
                                previousWords.push(this.state.apiWord);
                                console.log("Loss: before state updated: this.state.previousWords: ", this.state.previousWords);
                                console.log("Loss: before state updated: let previousWords: ", previousWords);

                                
                                this.setState({
                                    previousWords: this.state.apiWord,
                                    pageLock: true,
                                    losses: this.state.losses + 1,
                                }, () => {
                                    console.log("Loss: after setState: this.state.previousWords: ", this.state.previousWords);

                                    this.resetGame();
                                    setTimeout(() => {

                                        // this.setWord();
                                    }, 5000);
                                });
```

Console log where the state is being set. "test" was added to the initial state for testing purposes.

```
after API call: this.state.previousWords:  ["test"]
App.js:209 Loss: before state updated: this.state.previousWords:  ["test"]
App.js:210 Loss: before state updated: let previousWords:  (2) ["test", "unintermitting"]
```

Comment: It means `previousWords` is defined, but not an array. Log its value to the console and it will probably give you a good idea of the problem. My guess is its a string since `.length` does not break. How are you setting its value?

Comment: I added that code in the edit. It is initiated as an array in the state and the apiWord pushed into a temporary array before being sent to the state to avoid mutating.

Comment: What do you think `this.setState({ previousWords: this.state.apiWord, ... })` is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you correctly build out the new array, but then do not use it to update state:

```js
let previousWords = [...this.state.previousWords];
previousWords.push(this.state.apiWord);

this.setState({
  previousWords: this.state.apiWord, // Should be previousWords: previousWords
  pageLock: true,
  losses: this.state.losses + 1,
},
```

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes it takes four eyes and two brains to figure out something something that simple.

Answer (score 0):

this.state.previousWords is not an Array that's why you're getting the error.
Easiest way to prevent it - check if this.state.previousWords is an Array `Array.isArray(this.state.previousWords)` and only then use `map`.

```
Array.isArray(this.state.previousWords) && this.state.previousWords.length
```

Comment: You are right. I just added a line to log it and it is showing after the state is updated it is no longer an array. Now to figure out why and were it is stops being an array...

Comment: Thank you for pointing in the right direction. I found a syntax error where I was setting the state with the wrong variable...

Comment: Checking if it is an array will stop the error, but will only hide the bug. This pattern is helpful when the array is not initially defined, but is harmful when the variable is the incorrect datatype.